# Waiting for new tab to open completely before printing the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print a certain content from my project i am opening a new tab using `window.open` and using print function to print the page but as the new tab is not loaded completely the page is not getting printed.

```
function PrintElem(elem){
            var mywindow = window.open('https://www.example.com/test/test?id=10');
            mywindow.document.onreadystatechange=function(){
             if(mywindow.document.readyState==='complete'){
              mywindow.focus();
              mywindow.print();
              mywindow.close();
             }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Is the new window on the same domain as you starting page? This could be a Same-origin policy issue ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy )

Comment: yes same domain. The data loads after the print preview opens so the print is not able to capture the view to print.

Comment: You should add a javascript tag to this question!

Comment: Did you try already to put mywindow.onload in condition? if(mywindow.onload){mywindow.print(); mywindow.close()}

Comment: Is the data you're trying to print loaded via JS after the page is loaded? You may be waiting for the wrong thing to finish.

Comment: it's the page on the link that has to be printed. But the scripts are getting executed before the page load.

Comment: @emjr i tried it's not working

Comment: Try to check the `mywindow.document.readyState` property to be equal to `complete` before you call the `print`

Comment: @RannieAguilarPeralta I have updated the question, The event is not being captured.